# Minecraft 1.10 DeathLootTable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Could someone please explain how to edit a mob's drop chance of an item
or how to add an item to their loot table?

Even better, tell me how to use those other crazy tags, like `enchant_randomly` or `furnace_smelt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default loot tables are located in `assets\minecraft\loot_tables` within your Minecraft jar. Find the one you want to alter (e.g: `entities\creeper.json`) then copy it to `data\loot_tables\minecraft\...` (create the folders if they don't exist) in your world folder:

[image: Overwriting creeper loot table]

The first folder after `data\loot_tables` is called a "namespace" and loot tables must all be within one (you cannot place a loot table directly into `data\loot_tables`). In this case I'm using the `minecraft` namespace to overwrite the creeper's loot table.

If you don't want to overwrite the default drops for all of a certain type of mob, but instead want to summon specific mods with this new loot table, you should place the loot tables into another namespace, such as `realordsloottables`.

If you open up the loot table, it should look something like this:

[image: Loot table]

If you want to edit these manually, I'd recommend looking at some of the default ones for examples, and reading [this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table). There's a lot of things you can do and it's all already documented there.

To manually add a new item, you could copy paste the item already in this pool, and change its name. Here, I've given the creeper a possibility to drop between 16 and 32 stone:

[image: Loot table edited]

I'd recommend using a generator to simplify the process, then copy and pasting the output into the loot table:

- [Minecraft.Tools's generator has an easy interface, but doesn't allow for all of the features loot tables offer](http://minecraft.tools/en/loots.php) (see [Skylinerw's post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2687744-help-loot-tables#c8))
- [MrPingouin's generator is feature-complete and up to date](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPingouin/125mx5r5/embedded/result/)

---

After changing and saving the loot table, the mob's drops should now be changed. If you saved it in a custom namespace because you want it to only affect certain mobs, then you should summon the mobs like this:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {DeathLootTable:"namespacename:folder/loottablename"}
```

Comment: The linked generator is outdated as well as missing a large number of features that are key to using loot tables (I list out the issues with it [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2687744-help-loot-tables?comment=8)). [This generator](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPingouin/125mx5r5/embedded/result/), while not as visually-appealing, is both up-to-date and feature-complete.

Comment: @Skylinerw Added that generator to the post (and bookmarked for future use). Wonder if there's a way to contact the creators of Minecraft.Tools, since some of those problems (like the incorrect weight min) seem like they could be easy fixes.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find assets\minecraft\loot_tables or data\loot_tables\minecraft.  Help!

Comment: Do I need to worry about pools or rolls or weight?

Comment: @ReaLord If you want it to come with your map, put it in `assets\minecraft\loot_tables`. If you want it to affect every map, put it in data